# Approximate the solutions to the following parabolic partial-differential equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Use the:
a)forward difference method 
b)backward difference method
c)Cranck-Nicolson algorithm to approximate the solution of the parabolic partial differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial  x^2}=0,\ 0<x<4\,,0<t\ ;$$
$$\ u(0,t)=\ u(4,t)=\ 0\ ,\  0<\ t\ ,$$
$$\ u(x,0)=\ \sin(\frac{\pi}{4})(1+2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}x)\ ,\ 0\leq x\leq4\ .$$

What are the steps that I have to make to approximate the solution of this PDE? Can I do it by hand or a software is needed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including this information  helps others to know what exactly you are having difficulty with. This is important as there are several steps: 1) discretising in space; 2) discretising in time; 3) implementing the discretisation in numerical software; and 4) comparing the methods in some meaningful way (not explicitly mentioned in your question, but assumed due to the nature of the question).

Comment: You can put the scheme by hand, but for computing the actual approximation, you have to implement it on a computer.